# Angular 2 http header seems to be generated or send incorrectly

Tags: angularjs, http, header, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to send a request to my backend which uses HTTP Basic auth for authentication.
For testing purposes

```
username: user
password: password
```

so the correct header is:

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

I have tested the request with this header in Chrome Advanced Rest Extension and it works:

[image]

I generated the request in Angular2 like this:

```
  public getCurrentCounter() {
    console.log("Method getCurrentCounter() in CounterService called");

    var request = this.backendURL + "counter";
    var header = this.generateHeader(this.username, this.password);
    console.log(header);

    return this._http.get(request, {
      headers: header
    })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  /**
   * Generate HTTP header using HTTP basic Auth
   */
  private generateHeader(username, password) {

    var base64Creds = btoa(username + ":" + password);
    var auth = 'Basic ' + base64Creds;
    console.log(auth);
    var authHeader = new Headers();
    authHeader.append("Authorization", auth);

    return authHeader;
  }
```

I logged the generated Header Object and it looks like this:

[image]

Still I get this response:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/counter. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

Anybody an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: is the webserver running on the same port of your application?

Comment: no, backend on 8080, frontend 8081

Comment: okay, I was thinking it, then is CORS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So turns out the problem was on the backend.

The backend expected the `OPTIONS` request to be base authenticated as well, but since the `OPTIONS` request sent from angular2 doesn't have the Authentication Headers, we got an 401 response.

Limiting the request types which are expected to be authenticated on the backend fixed the issue.

Comment: Using Angular 2 RTM with ASP.NET Core (full fx) and when it came to calling a secure api, I had to add the following to my API (server):

`public static class CorsBuilder
{
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCors(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(x =>
            {
                x.AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });

            return app;
        }
}`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to CORS which is not enabled on the server side.

Your service must answer an OPTIONS request with headers like these:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: [the same ACCESS-CONTROL-REQUEST-HEADERS from request]
```

Here is a good doc: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server

also look at this: [Chrome v37/38 CORS failing (again) with 401 for OPTIONS pre-flight requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296779/chrome-v37-38-cors-failing-again-with-401-for-options-pre-flight-requests)

for the basic authentication in angularjs 1.x could you please try:

```
service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
    var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
    $http.defaults.headers.common = {"Access-Control-Request-Headers": "accept, origin, authorization"}; //you probably don't need this line.  This lets me connect to my server on a different domain
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; // jshint ignore:line

        };
```

for the Angularjs 2.x version please have a look at:

[Angular2 - set headers for every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request)

I found extending the BaseRequestOptions very interesting:

```
class MyRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + authdata);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly did not solve the issue. Also if this would be a CORS issue there would be a 403 response not a 401

Comment: 401 Unauthorized is the HTTP status code for authentication errors. Is your server behind a basic authentication?

Comment: yes and the header for the basic authentication seems to not be set up correctly that the issue here

Comment: $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata is the trick

Comment: What do you mean with $http? The http object does not have a `defaults` field.

Comment: Using Angular 2 RTM with ASP.NET Core (full fx) and when it came to calling a secure api, I had to add the following to my API (server): 

`public static class CorsBuilder
{
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCors(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(x =>
            {
                x.AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });

            return app;
        }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Either you forgot to import the `Headers` class. Either you need to set the `withCredentials` property to `true` on the underlying XHR of your request.

To do that, you can do the following. First extend the `BrowserXhr`:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor() {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

and override the `BrowserXhr` provider with the extended class:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
]);
```

Comment: Tried, sadly issue persists

Answer (score -1):

Can you verify but it seems that you getting this error from an OPTIONS request ? and not a GET request.

Comment: Somehow the server is returning 401 for an options request which is weird. What framework do you use ?

Comment: do you mean on the backend?

Comment: Yes sorry on the backend

Comment: Spring Boot, but as I said when do the request in the browser or in the chrome rest extension it will work fine.

Comment: Yes but in the chrome rest extension its probably not an ajax request so there is no OPTIONS preflight request. Try to call the api with the chrome rest extension and the OPTIONS http method you should be able to reproduce the issue