# AngularJS HTTP headers config. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a Rest service with angular:

```
angular.module('coursExoApp').factory('serviceAjax', function ($http) {
return{
    objects: function(){
         var test=$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://------------/Windchill/servlet/rest/changes/objects/getReports',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic d2NhZG1pbjp3Y2FkbWlu'           
            }
            }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('success');
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(config);
            });

            return test;
    }
}});
```

and i'm getting this error:
[IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjhqS.png)

The service with basic authentification works fine with postMan.
thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with CORS, perhaps you need to modify the service to allow the origin of the request (Domain your app is running from) ?

[Chrome v37/38 CORS failing (again) with 401 for OPTIONS pre-flight requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296779/chrome-v37-38-cors-failing-again-with-401-for-options-pre-flight-requests)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS